# How to query and get a specific field within a user's related data (ManytoMany)

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-views, django-templates

what I am trying to do is that I am trying to query and get all departmental_goals thats available to the user based on the departments they are in, to pass into the template as a context.

So lets say, a manager creates a departmental goal, this departmental goal(that has a department field) will be available to all users based on the department they are in, defined within the department field of user.Profile. However, I have no idea how to get about this, **I tried this query** but it has failed and I have no idea why, can someone push me in the right direction

**Query I tried**

```
 departmental_goals_database = Departmental_Goals.objects.get(department = request.user.profile.departments_set.all()[0].name)
```

**Views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url = 'login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['Employee'])

def User_GnC(request):

    #Get user's profile and retrieve all departmental goals (Not fixed yet)
    departmental_goals_database = Departmental_Goals.objects.get(department = request.user.profile.departments_set.all()[0].name)

#context to pass into template
    context ={
        "departmental_goals_list":departmental_goals_database
    }
    return render(request,'GnC/HuNet_GnC.html', context)
```

**Profile models**

```
#Class profile one-to-one linked to user + many-to-many linked to department
class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null = True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank = False, null = False)

    email = models.EmailField(blank = False, null = False)

    department = models.ManyToManyField(Departments, blank = False, null = False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Departments models**

```
#Department model of employee thats linked to Profile through one-to-many
class Departments(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank = False, null = True)

    Managers = models.ForeignKey('Profile', blank = True, null = True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Departmental goals**

```
class Departmental_Goals(models.Model):
    manager = models.ForeignKey(Profile, blank = False, null = True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Departments, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=False, null = False)
    goal_category = models.ManyToManyField(goal_category)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.summary
```